# Arabic and other Right-to-left slugs ok?

Tags: browser, arabic, slug, right-to-left

I'm creating a multi-lingual site, where an item has a slug for each of the sites languages.

For Arabic slugs (and I assume any other right-to-left languages) it acts strange when you try to highlight it. The cursor moves opposite while in the RTL text..etc.  This isn't a terribly big deal, but it made me think that maybe it's not "normal" or "ok".

I've seen some sites with Arabic slugs, but I've also seen completely Arabic sites that still use English slugs.

Is there a benefit one way or the other?  A suggested method?  Is doing it the way I am ok?  Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that by "slug" you mean a direct permanent URL to a page. If you don't, you can ignore the rest of this answer :)

Such URLs will work, but avoid them if you can. The fact that it's right-to-left is actually not the worst problem. The worst problem with any non-ASCII URL is that in a lot of contexts it will show like this: https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%86%D9%87%D8%B1_%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1 (it's just a link to a random article in the Arabic Wikipedia). You will see a long trail of percent signs and numbers, even if the title is short, because each non-ASCII characters will turn to about six ASCII characters. This gets very ugly when you have to paste it in an email, for example.

I write a blog in Hebrew and I manually change the slug of every post to some ASCII name.